# Write down the eqn. of the line that passes through the points $(4, -2, 1)$ and $(6, 0, 3)$ in all three forms.

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, geometric-algebras

I'm stuck because I can't find the parallel vector. Do you know how to find it?
I'd just assumed that vector r0 = <4, -2, 1>.

Answer (score 0):

It's $$(6-4,0-(-2),3-1)=(2,2,2)=2(1,1,1).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Thank you! You saved my life!! XD

Comment: @Supakorn Srisawat You are welcome!